# Splice returns the deleted element instead of returning all other elements that was not deleted

Tags: angular6

```
getAllClients() {
    this.clientsService.getClients()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.clients= data.splice(22, 1);
        //this.clients = data;
      },
      error => {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Was this question answered?

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the documentation for splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you will realise that it is a mutable operation. This means that when you use splice, you are: 1) returning the spliced part of the array. 2) Mutating the original data object.

Example:

```
 let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 const b = a.splice(2, 1); // b is now [3]
 console.log(a); // the rest of the array [1, 2, 4]
```

So basically instead of saving this.clients with data.splice(22, 1). You should execute first

```
data.splice(22, 1);
```

and then assign the result to clients

```
this.clients = data;
```

I will still recommend you to use an immutable way of manipulating the data like this [Ramda function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#remove)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `splice` changes the array and returns the deleted elements. The not-deleted elements are, unsurprisingly, in the array.

If you want to delete 22th element from an array and assign the array to `this.clients`, this is a correct way to do it:

```
data.splice(22, 1);
this.client = data;
```

If you want `this.client` to have one element less but for `data` to be untouched, you will have to clone it:

```
this.client = data.slice();
this.client.splice(22, 1);
```